# Right Angles on Incircle Chord Lemma

Tags: geometry

The incircle of $△ABC$ is tangent to $BC, CA, AB$ at $D, E, F,$ respectively. Let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of $BC$ and $AC$, respectively. Ray $ BI$ meets line $EF$ at $K$. Show that $BK ⊥ CK.$ Then show $K$ lies on line $MN.$

If $M,N,K$ collinear then $MK//AB$ and$\angle MBK=\angle MKB$ and hence $BM=KM=CM$, which is sufficient to prove that $\angle BKC=90º$. But idk how to prove MNK collinear. I tried reverse reconstruction but it didn't really work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the point I?

Comment: the incenter of triangle ABC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\angle DEK = 180^{\circ} - \angle DEF = 180^{\circ} - \angle DFB = 90^{\circ} + \angle FBI = 90^{\circ} + \angle DBI = \angle DIK$ (the reasons in order are: angle in a straight line, alternate segment theorem, $BI \perp DF$, $BI$ bisects $\angle ABC$, and exterior angle equals sum of interior opposite angles in a triangle), so $DIEK$ is cyclic.

However, $DIEC$ is cyclic as $ID \perp CD$, $IE \perp CE$, so we get $DIEKC$ cyclic. This gives $\angle BKC = \angle BDI = 90^{\circ}$, so $BK \perp CK$.

Proving $M$, $N$, $K$ collinear now follows almost immediately, as $M$ is the circumcentre of $(CKB)$ by Thales' Theorem, so $MK=MB$, resulting in $\angle MKB = \angle KBM = \angle KBA$, so $MK||AB$. This is then finished by Midpoint Theorem, so $M, N, K$ collinear.